# Conditional formatting, greater than a year in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, conditional-formatting

I am working on a spreadsheet that logs the dates parts were sent out and would like to apply conditional formatting to the dates.

I would like if over 3 years ago, if over 2 years ago, if over 1, if this year... then format appropriately. I have looked around Google and found some formulas but not the ones I need/work. So far I have this, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
3 years  : =TODAY()-$E$26<=1065    
2 years  : =TODAY()-$E$26<=730    
1 year   : =TODAY()-$E$26<=365    
This year: =TODAY()-$E$26<=1
```

I fixed the years by changing the `<` sign to `>`, my mistake - but am still having trouble with the `if this year`. I would expect something like `if < 365` to work, but it doesn't. For example, May 2011 is displaying the formatting for less than a year, even though it's not.

Comment: Ok, 

all fixed- wouldn't let me answer question myself yet

less than 1 year =TODAY()-$E$26<=365

1 year = =TODAY()-$E$26>=365

2 years = =TODAY()-$E$26>=730

3 years =TODAY()-$E$26>=1065

Comment: glad you figured it out